# Fetch particular text from another file (python)

Tags: python

I have a file of the following pattern:

```
"abcd.asxs." "alphabets"
"wedf.345.po&%12." "numbers"
"xyhd.iu*u." "characters"
"megaten4.koryaku-memo.xyz." "alphabets"
"adwdbk.uyequ." "alphabets"
"233432.2321." "numbers"
"tytqyw.sdfhgwq." "alphabets"
```

I want something like:

```
string[0]=abcd.asxs
string[1]=megaten4.koryaku-memo.xyz
string[2]=tytqyw.sdfhgwq
and so on....
```

What code I have written is:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 import re

 important = []
 needed_categories = ["alphabets"]

 with open('file.txt') as fp:
        rec=fp.readlines()

 for line in rec:
        for category in needed_categories:
                if category in line:
                        important.append(line)
                        break
 print("\n".join(important))
```

Output I get:

"abcd.asxs." "alphabets"

"megaten4.koryaku-memo.xy." "alphabets"

"tytqyw.sdfhgwq." "alphabets"

Comment: What is the pattern you are looking for? What is the output you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Points for your code:**

- You can iterate line by line using file handle directly. No need to save file data using `fp.readlines()` in list and then iterating.
- Once needed_category is found, you are directly appending complete line. That's why you are getting wrong output. You need to split line and save first element only.
- Didn't understand why you used `break`.

**Working Code :**

```
important = []
needed_categories = ["alphabets"]

with open('a.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        temp = []
        for category in needed_categories:
            if category in line:
                temp = line.split()
                important.append(temp[0].replace('"','').strip("."))
print((important)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
['abcd.asxs', 'megaten4.koryaku-memo.xyz', 'adwdbk.uyequ', 'tytqyw.sdfhgwq']

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Comment: Works but I don't need the . at the end and also I want each one of them as a single index of a list so I can run a for loop against it.

Comment: Something like:
important[0]= abcd.asxs
important[1]=megaten4.koryaku-memo.xyz
important[2]=adwdbk.uyequ
important[3]=tytqyw.sdfhgwq

Comment: @Harsh - Check the updated code. Removed '.' from end.

Comment: @Harsh - 'important' was already list on which you can iterate.

Answer (score 0):

change `important.append(line)` to:

`if line.strip().endswith('"alphabets"'):
  important.append(line.split(' ')[0].strip('"').strip('''))`